# Ignition wire breaks while driving

Tags: immobilizer

I'm putting an immobilizer on the ignition circuitry.  Worst case scenarios, if the immobilizer, (normally closed relay), broke what would happen?

Would the car continue as normal and then not start up or would in cut out while driving?

Comment: I think we'd need to know what the model of the immobilizer is so we could then figure out where it fits into the ignition system, then we might be able to answer your question.

Comment: It's a custom design.  It's meant to go on the starter circuit.  Starter wire is broken and feeds into the immobiliser. The device consists of a relay and various control components.  IT is normally closed, so if the power went it would remain closed.  My question is, if you are driving and the device broke causing the starter wire to open would it interfere with the car?

Comment: From your *description*, I'd say it would not affect how the car runs, but once shut down would not start again. Start circuit and run circuit are two different things on most vehicles. With out the complete wiring diagram, there is no way to say for sure.